# EE v2.5.3 + SafeCracker Registration = Invalid activation request

Tags: members, safecracker, safecracker-registration

I'm trying to create a SafeCracker form to register users (I'm using SafeCracker Registration). Registration form only has 3 fields:

- email
- password
- password_confirm

When I enter all the fields and click submit, all seems to go well. I receive an email that says I need to activate my account. When I click the link, I am redirected to a page that says:

```
Error
Invalid activation request.
```

However, it seems like the registration process worked, though. I see my account in the member group id that I defined the in SafeCracker registration tag pair. **Any ideas what's causing "Invalid activation request?"**

Also, should I be seeing newly registered profiles immediately in the group member I defined? Or should it go to "Pending" first?

**UPDATE 1:**

If `group_id` parameter is not specified in the tag pair, registrants go from "Pending" prior to activating, then to "Members" after activating. No more "Invalid activation request" error.

Comment: So if there still an issue when you remove group_id? Also, did you get the latest version I sent to you? Happy to help you in any way I can, I just need to be able to duplicate this error.

Comment: @JustinKimbrell - yes, using the latest SafeCracker Registration. Problem seems to only exist if I set the `group_id` parameter.

Comment: Ok, I will take a look into that issue and report back.

Comment: Still working on this issue. Hoping to have a resolution at some point today.

Comment: Thanks. So the bug is confirmed? And about my other question, should I be seeing newly registered profiles immediately in the group member I defined? Or should it go to "Pending" first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally had a chance to dive down into this issue and figure out what's wrong. Due to the way the activations work, the member will go in the Pending group.

You can set the default member group so once the member is activated, they go into a designated member group. From there they can edit their profile and group_id parameter will work. The group_id param just doesn't work when there is member activation in place.

To set a default member group go to:

Members > Preferences > Default Member Group Assigned to New Members